# Creating a __str__ function in preorder for a binary tree

Tags: python, string, oop, binary-tree

I am creating a prefix parser class in Python and I have already created the tree itself, and I am able to create an operation to print the tree in preorder, it looks like this:

```
def print_preorder(self):
    self.print_preorder_recur(self.root)
    print("")

def print_preorder_recur(self,node):

    if node==None:
        return None

    print(str(node.data),end=" ")
    self.print_preorder_recur(node.left)
    self.print_preorder_recur(node.right)
```

but I am struggling with creating a **str** operation that returns a string with the same information the print_preorder operation prints out.

Three tree in my code has a root and a last node, and per node has a left, right, parent and then the data in it.

Do you have any recommendations on how to create this operation?

Answer (score -1):

I would simplify the whole thing so that the `__str__` method itself is printing the children and then to print the whole tree you could just print the root.
So you could make the recursion happen in the method itself like that:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{node.data} {node.left} {node.right}"
```

And then print the whole tree with `print(root)`.